# GastbyJS and Contentful: my node appears to be undefined?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, contentful

In my pages/about.js file, I've created a query to grab two images and a text, from Contentful. The query works in GraphiQL with no problems, but when I try to use the data inside my About component, I get this error:

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening, as the query seems to be correctly written? Where have I gone wrong, here?

Here is my component code and query:

```
const About = ({data}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hi from the about page</h1>
    <p>Welcome to page about</p>
    <img src={data.allContentfulProfile.edges.node.emblem.file.url} />
  </div>
)

export default About

export const aboutQuery = graphql`
  query aboutQuery {
    allContentfulProfile (
      filter: {
        node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}
    },
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          logo {
            file {
              url
            }
          }
          emblem {
            file {
              url
            }
          } 
          aboutText {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              html
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `aboutQuery` to `pageQuery` otherwise it will be ignored by Gatsby.

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query aboutQuery {
    allContentfulProfile (
      filter: {
        node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}
    },
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          logo {
            file {
              url
            }
          }
          emblem {
            file {
              url
            }
          } 
          aboutText {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              html
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Edges is an array, it should be edges[0].emblem